# user defined conversion c++ using operator keyword - const or no const

Tags: c++, c++11

With user defined conversion in C++ using the operator keyword, for example

```
class X {
private:
   int _x;
public:
   operator int() const { return _x; } 
};
```

how does the const qualifier change anything vs. not have a const qualifier? It seems that regardless of having const or no const, I would still need to assign to an lvalue like this:

```
X x;
const int &foo = x;
```

Comment: Non-const operator won't work when an instance of `X` itself is const: `const X x; int n = x;` [Demo](http://rextester.com/VGB55267)

Comment: There's no need for the reference, it only introduces a needless temporary (with life extension). The `const`-ness of a member function determines whether it can be called on a `const` instance of the class.

Comment: Oh whoops, yes, this is a duplicate. Sorry about that. I kept searching around a limited context of a user defined conversion using the operator keyword when also used with const.